# What is this equipment called?

Tags: motor, dc, generator

In this video at 0:40, what is the equipment he is using to power the motor? It seems to be some sort of torque leveraged device (forgive my ignorance).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=6kgzrXFSDwA#t=40s

Comment: hand cranked dynamo maybe

Comment: Just a PM motor attached to a gearbox and a hand-crank.  Essentially a duplicate of the demo around 0:20, but with a PM motor that is spun faster.

Comment: So it is the gears that leverage the force to torque. Is this process multiplying force from the muscle to the motor rotation or is the muscle force equal to the mechanical force exerted from the motor?

Answer (score 1):

The unit is a motor driven by a gearbox.
 A driven motor is a genertor or alternetor (subject to cetain conditions), which is the point he is making.

The motor speed is **increased** by gearbox action so the voltage produced is greater than without the gearbox as Vout is ~ proportional to speed.

Re torques - it's a gearbox with a motor on the end.
Standard gearbox dynamics apply.
The force on the higher speed end -  actually the torque, which is rotational force, will be **LOWER** at **higher** speed.

Power = k x torque x RPM. So

RPM_In x Torque_In x efficiency  = RPM_Out x Torque_Out  or

Torque_Out = RPM_In / RPM_Out x Torque_In x efficiency